# How to map a List of enum into a Varchar using Hibernate 6.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, mapping

I'm currently trying to make a custom Hibernate Type to map a List of Enum into a Varchar of comma-separated elements. For that, I've written my own JavaType (old JavaTypeDescriptor) and my own BasicType. The problem is, for my second class, that I need an instance of my JavaType.

### Attempt 1

In Hibernate 5, it was possible to set the JavaType when needed, using the Parameter annotation and by setting in it the type (with `AbstractStandardBasicType#setJavaTypeDescriptor`). In the version 6.2 of Hibernate, the method is not available anymore and the field javaTypeDescriptor (now javaType) is final, so I'm not able to do it.
Here is the code I've tried :

```
public class EnumListJavaType<E extends Enum<E>> extends AbstractJavaType<List<E>> {

    private final Class<E> enumClass;

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ",";

    public EnumListJavaType(Class<E> enumClass) {
        super(List.class);
        this.enumClass = enumClass;
    }

    @Override
    public <X> X unwrap(List<E> value, Class<X> type, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return (X) toString(value);
    }

    @Override
    public <X> List<E> wrap(X value, WrapperOptions options) {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        return fromString(value.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(List<E> value) {
        return (String) value.stream()
                .map(Enum::name)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(SEPARATOR));
    }

    public List<E> fromString(String string) {
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(string))
            return null;
        return Arrays.stream(string.split(SEPARATOR))
                .map(s -> Enum.valueOf(enumClass, s))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

```
public class EnumListType<E extends Enum<E>> extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<List<E>> implements DynamicParameterizedType {


    /**
     * Here the JavaType is not passed as we don't know yet the enum class.
     */
    public EnumListType() {
        super(VarcharJdbcType.INSTANCE, null);

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "enum_list";
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getRegistrationKeys() {
        return new String[] { getName(), "EnumList", EnumSet.class.getName() };
    }

    @Override
    public void setParameterValues(Properties parameters) {
// Here I'm not able to set the JavaType anymore as there is no such method
/*        String enumClassName = (String) parameters.get("enumClass");

        try {
            setJavaType(new EnumSetJavaType(Class.forName(enumClassName)));
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {}*/
    }
```

The only way I see now is by removing the generic and to define my JavaType as a List. But I hope there is a more clean way of doing this.

### Attempt 2

I've then thought about creating a Factory to create the HavaType when needed, by using the annotation @TypeDef. Something like :

```
public class EnumListTypeFactory implements TypeDef {

    @Override
    public Class getTypeClass() {
        return EnumListType.class;
    }

    @Override
    public String getTypeMethod() {
        return "forEnumClass";
    }

    public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumListType forEnumClass(String enumClassName) {
        try {
            Class<E> enumClass = (Class<E>) Class.forName(enumClassName);
            return new EnumListType<>(new EnumListJavaType<>(enumClass));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new HibernateException("Enum class not found", e);
        }
    }
```

But in Hibernate 6, the annotation @TypeDef seems to have been removed.

I will be grateful if you have any suggestion about it !

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a varchar column in the database, I think all you need is to supply

```
<E extends Enum<E>> AttributeConverter<EnumSet<E>, String>
```

Except for using `Set` instead of `EnumSet`, I think you can grab an implementation [here](https://jorgepadilla.es/blog/implementing-a-generic-enum-jpa-attribute-converter-in-java).

A non-generified version appears in the [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.3/introduction/html_single/Hibernate_Introduction.html) (section 3.12).